Where should I store my application data (i.e. json, images and some audio files)?
I have a top-bar setup that requires some additional files:

icons.json for icons used in that bar.

Some custom .pngs like google-calendar.png, user.png.

Some .mp3 files like notify.mp3 for incoming notifications.


Now the configuration file for this bar is stored under ~/.config and I want these additional files to be specific to the current user only too. A different user must set his bar up himself.
Another thing is some of these files won't change (i.e. google-calendar.png, notify.mp3) and some will (i.e. events.json containing calendar events).
In that case what's the best way to store these files?

The XDG Base Directory Specification is your friend:
Your data files (so icons, images, sound files) should end up in $XDG_DATA_HOME; if unset, that would default to ~/.local/share/; it's a bit up to you how you organize below, but I'd generally say ~/.local/share/{your application's name}/ would be a good idea

Thank you! I was also thinking the same. Also is it ok to put data that changes during runtime (i.e. events.json for calendar events) in ~/.local/state/{app_name}?

I don't know what events.json stores, whether it's data, configuration, state, or cache. I'd 100% go by the word-for-word text in the standard I linked to.

Yeah it's events related data like 2024-11-27-10-00-00: {"task": "Buy breads"}

I can't tell whether that's data, state, cache or configuration. but you can! And then just check the document,
